# How to catch one specific mysql error in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, mysqli

I've got a mysqli_query inside a try block like below:

```
    try {
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
```

I'm trying to catch a

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Data too long for
> column ...

error so I can display a PHP message on the page. At the moment since it's a fatal error it just crashes the script and I can't display anything.

I've tried putting `mysqli_query($db,$sql);` in a `try/catch` block but the issue persists. I've read elsewhere that setting `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` might help - I've tried putting that before the query but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a rare case when using try catch around SQL query execution is justified.

In order to handle one specific SQL error, you may add a condition inside the `catch` block that is looking for the specific error, either using `getCode()` or `getMessage()`, and then, if found, handle it the way you like. While using `throw $e;` otherwise, so all other errors will be handled  the usual way elsewhere:

```
try {
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if (str_starts_with($e->getMessage(),"Data too long for column")) {
        // handle the error
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```